# Android StartActivity ForResult when press back, it takes me to home screen

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

The concept is Acticity(A)  ==> Activity(B).   [ Same App]

When press back button goes to Activity(A).

it used to work with this code.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, NextActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

now i want to get data back from Activity(B) when user click some button. i change the code to.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, NextActivity.class);
//startActivity(intent); //old one
startActivityForResult(intent, TableStatusActivity.ORDER_REQUEST);
```

it works when user click some button and i get back the data, and Activity(A) shows.

BUT WHEN PRESS BACK **IN ACTIVITY(B)**, IT GOES TO HOME SCREEN.  <== WHICH I DO NOT WANT.

how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    // do whatever you need to do here
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I added  setResult(RESULT_OK, new Intent()); and it works

Answer (score 0):

Use **OnActivityResult** method in Activity(A) to get data from Activity(B). Click  http://www.javatpoint.com/android-startactivityforresult-example for details.